# Show that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_{j}$ is Cauchy distributed when the $X_{i}$ are all Cauchy

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

Let $X_{1}, \cdots, X_{n}$ be i.i.d. Cauchy random variables with parameters $\alpha=0$ and $\beta=1$. (That is, their density is $f(x)=\frac{1}{\pi\,(1+x^{2})}$, $-\infty < x < \infty$.) Show that $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}X_{j}$ also has a Cauchy distribution.

We are given the hint to use characteristic functions, but I am wondering if there is an easier way to approach this problem.

I tried some stuff using the fact that the $X_{i}$ are independent, but it really didn't go anywhere, so any help you could give would be most appreciated!

Comment: Since you tagged this question with "characteristic functions" you must know that a random variable has the Cauchy distribution if and only if its characteristic function is $e^{-|t|}$.

Comment: Yes, I do know that, but I was not able to use that to help me. I was able to show that $\varphi(u_{1},\cdots u_{n}) = exp(-(|u_{1}+u_{2}+\cdots+ u_{n}|))$, but that doesn't really gave anything to do with $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_{j}$. Instead, should I try to take a sum of the characteristic functions? But then, how do I combine them all together to make one characteristic function?

Comment: If $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are independent, then $\chi_{X_1+\cdots+X_n}(t) = \chi_{X_1}(t)\cdots\chi_{X_n}(t)$.  Also $\chi_{a X}(t) = \chi_X(at)$.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to post an answer; can you tell me if it's okay?

Comment: Sure - but I'm going to bed soon.

Comment: In any case, thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

$\varphi_{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_{j}}(u)=\varphi_{\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_{j}}(\frac{1}{n}u) = \varphi_{X_{1}+X_{2}+\cdots +X_{n}}(\frac{1}{n}u)=\varphi_{X_{1}}(\frac{1}{n}u)\varphi_{X_{2}}(\frac{1}{n}u)\cdots\varphi_{X_{n}}(\frac{1}{n}u)$

And since each of the $X_{i}$ is Cauchy distributed,

$=\exp(-|\frac{1}{n}u|)\cdot\exp(-|\frac{1}{n}u|)\cdots\exp(-|\frac{1}{n}u|) = \exp(-\frac{1}{n}|u|)\cdot\exp(-\frac{1}{n}|u|) \cdots\exp(-\frac{1}{n}|u|)=\exp(-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}|u|)=\exp(-\frac{1}{n}\cdot n \cdot |u|)=\exp(-|u|) $.

By the uniqueness of characteristic functions, we have that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_{j}$ is also Cauchy-distributed.

Comment: Looks good to me.